# What am I doing wrong here? I am new to python

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Complete the body of the function sign (with signature below) in agreement with
>   the details specified above.
>
> ```
> def sign(t):
>     "Returns +1 for t>=0, -1 otherwise"
> ```

solution:

```
def sign(t):

sign = lambda t: -1 if t < 0 else 1 if t >=0
```

Above shows syntax error. What am I doing wrong here? it kind of shows name 'sign' not defined

Comment: Can you share the exact code you are running?

Comment: sign = lambda t: -1 if t < 0 else 1 if t >=0    ( after the line - def sign(t): )

Comment: Please edit your question to contain all code. Additionally explain how you run that code

Comment: First, the second line of your solution should be indented. Second, you are confused with the way ternary operators work with Python. You should have only one `if` and one `else`

Comment: Don’t assign a `lambda` to a variable (https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/assigning_a_lambda_to_a_variable.html).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like all you need a is small function. Is this what you're looking for?

```
def sign(t):
    if t < 0:
        return -1
    else:
        return 1
```

Also, one thing is wrong with your lambda. If you expand it as if it was a normal function it would look like this:

```
def sign(t):
    if t < 0:
        return -1
    else:
       return 1 if t >= 0
```

So, there are only two cases. Either t is less than 0, or it is greater than or equal to zero. So, the following code will work:

```
sign = lambda t: -1 if t < 0 else 1
print(sign(2)) # will return 1
```

Comment: Don’t assign a `lambda` to a variable (https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/assigning_a_lambda_to_a_variable.html).

Answer (score 0):

By itself,

```
def sign(t):
    "Returns +1 for t>=0, -1 otherwise"
```

is a syntactically complete function definition. It doesn't *do* anything, (except return `None`) but the docstring is sufficient to make the body non-empty, as if you had defined it as

```
def sign(t):
    pass
```

instead.

What you need to do is add an *actual* body to the function so that it behaves the way the docstring describes.

```
def sign(t):
    "Returns +1 for t>=0, -1 otherwise"
    if t >= 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1
```

or

```
def sign(t):
    "Returns +1 for t>=0, -1 otherwise"
    return 1 if t >= 0 else -1
```